# Check if a method is an alias to another method in rspec

Tags: ruby, methods

`Article#to_archive` is an alias for `Article#archived!`:

```
class Article
  alias to_archive archived!
end
```

I need to ensure this, so I wrote this test:

```
describe '#to_archive' do
  it 'is an alias to #archived!' do
    expect(subject.method(:to_archive)).to eq(subject.method(:archived!))
  end
end
```

However, I receive an error

```
Failure/Error: expect(subject.method(:to_archive)).to eq(subject.method(:archived!))

   expected: #<Method: Article(#<Module:0x00000005a7c240>)#archived!>
        got: #<Method: Article(#<Module:0x00000005a7c240>)#to_archive(archived!)>
```

It used to work in ruby < 2.3 IIRC. I  tried `alias_method`, but it didn't help.

Comment: No it doesn't. It's also defined on the article instance, not as a class method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `Method#==` is not clear and/or useful, so you shouldn't rely on it.

To check that it is an alias, you can do this:

```
expect(subject.method(:to_archive).original_name).to eq(:archived!)
```